# Collisions in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, interface

As of late I have been programming a 2D sandbox populated with several shapes in motion, specifically circles. The speed and size of each circle can be controlled by a two JSlider at the top and bottom of the window.

**Animation Class**

```
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import java.awt.*;

public class Animation extends JFrame {

    public final int HEIGHT = 500;
    public final int WIDTH = 735;
    public int speed = 10, size = 50;
    JSlider sl1, sl2;
    JPanel panel, panel2;
    JLabel label, label2;
    GraphicsDemo gD;

    public Animation() {
        this.setSize(WIDTH+35,HEIGHT+90);
        this.getContentPane();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new JPanel(); panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        label = new JLabel("Current Speed: 10");
        label2 = new JLabel("Current Size: 50");

        Dimension length = label.getPreferredSize();
        label.setBounds(150, 200, length.width, length.height);
        setSlider();
        Animation.event e1 = new Animation.event();
        Animation.event e2 = new Animation.event();
        sl1.addChangeListener(e1);
        sl2.addChangeListener(e2);


        panel.add(sl1); panel2.add(sl2);
        panel.add(label); panel2.add(label2);
        gD = new GraphicsDemo(HEIGHT, WIDTH, speed, size, sl1, sl2);
        this.add(gD);

        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void setSlider() {
        sl1 = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 20, speed);
        sl1.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
        sl1.setPaintTicks(true);

        sl2 = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 20, 100, size);
        sl2.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
        sl2.setPaintTicks(true);
    }

    public class event implements ChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            speed = sl1.getValue();
            label.setText("Current speed: " + speed);

            size = sl2.getValue();
            label2.setText("Current size: " + size);
        }
    }
}
```

**GraphicsDemo Class**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GraphicsDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public ArrayList<Balls> balls = new ArrayList<>();
    Image spaceImage;
    JSlider sl, sl2;
    Timer timer;
    public int h, w, s, size;
    public GraphicsDemo(int WIDTH, int HEIGHT, int SPEED,
                        int SIZE, JSlider slide, JSlider slide2) {
        h = HEIGHT; w = WIDTH;
        sl = slide; sl2 = slide2;
        s = SPEED; size = SIZE;
        init();
        spaceImage = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\space.jpg").getImage();
        timer = new Timer(100, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void init() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int x = (int) ((Math.random()*700)+1);
            int y = (int) ((Math.random()*400)+1);
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                balls.add(new Balls(size, x, y, 10, -10));
            } else {
                balls.add(new Balls(size, x, y, -10, 10));
            }
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2D.drawImage(spaceImage, 0,0, 735, 490, null);

        GradientPaint paint = new GradientPaint(0,0,Color.RED, 420,0,Color.BLUE);
        g2D.setPaint(paint);
        for (Balls ball : balls) {
            ball.render(g2D);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (Balls ball : balls) {
            ball.checkBounds();
            ball.changeVel(sl);
            ball.changeSize(sl2);
            for(Balls b : balls) {
          //      ball.collision(b);
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }

    static class Balls {
        Shape oval;
        private int radius;
        private int cx;
        private int cy;
        private int velX, velY;


        Balls(int r, int x, int y, int velX, int velY) {
            this.radius = r;
            this.cx = x;
            this.cy = y;
            this.velX = velX;
            this.velY = velY;
            oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(cx, cy, radius, radius);
        }

        void checkBounds() {
            cx += velX;
            cy += velY;
            if (cx >= 735-radius || cx <= 0) {
                velX *= -1;
            }
            if (cy  >= 490-radius || cy  <= 0) {
                velY *= -1;
            }
        }

        public void collision(Balls o) {
            Area areaA = new Area(oval);
            areaA.intersect(new Area(o.oval));
            if (!areaA.isEmpty()) {
                velX *= -1;
            }
        }

        void changeVel(JSlider sl) {
            if (velX < 0) {
                velX = -sl.getValue();
            } else {
                velX = sl.getValue();
            }
            if(velY < 0) {
               velY = -sl.getValue();
            } else {
                velY = sl.getValue();
            }
        }

        void changeSize(JSlider sl) {
            radius = sl.getValue();
        }

        void render(Graphics2D g) {
            oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(cx, cy, radius, radius);
            g.fill(oval);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I have been stuck on creating an algorithm that not only handles all collisions between  objects, but also accurately plans a trajectory from which both shapes would move away from each other once coming in contact. As of now, I have hypothetical class that would handle these collisions, but after several attempts of testing this along with the rest of the program it has onl bugs or breaks in the program logic.

**Collision Class**

```
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Collisions {

    public boolean collision(ArrayList<GraphicsDemo.Balls> balls, Shape o1) {
        Area areaA = new Area(o1);
        for (GraphicsDemo.Balls ball : balls) {
            areaA.intersect(new Area(ball.oval));
            return !areaA.isEmpty();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any help or tips would be most helpful in figuring a viable solution for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: First, don't update the state of the component from with in the `paintComponent` method, you're setting yourself up for a high CPU load, as this can trigger new paint passes. Don't pass the sliders to the balls, you're exposing implementation details and risky unrestricted modifications to the components, better to set the value of the slider directly

Comment: [Simple Collision Detection](https://relativity.net.au/gaming/java/SimpleCollisionDetection.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your collision class :

```
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Collisions {

    public boolean collision(ArrayList<GraphicsDemo.Balls> balls, Shape o1) {
        Area areaA = new Area(o1);
        for (GraphicsDemo.Balls ball : balls) {
            areaA.intersect(new Area(ball.oval));
            return !areaA.isEmpty();  // HERE
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Your loop return a value without any assertion at the first step !